# re.search always returning NONE

Tags: python, python-re

I cannot seem to figure out why, regardless of what I seem to change, when I call re.search(), I always am returned NONE, as if the pattern is not present.

```
import re
from typing import Tuple, List
from collections import Counter
from glob import glob


def start_project(txt: str) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    
    print("before re.search")
    x = re.search("\*\*\* START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK .* \*\*\*", str(str))
    print("this is the new output: ", x)


start_project("*** START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK THE ILIAD ***")
```

Comment: What is this `str(str)`?

Comment: Would your regex pattern match this string `"<class 'str'>"` ?

Comment: That was me thinking the string inputted as the parameter was saved under the variable str and not txt.  I've never had that sort of function/parameter declaration method before and it completely threw me off.  I put swapped in txt for str(str) and  it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Need to change 2nd argument in re.search() call to the "txt" variable.

Try:

```
import re
from typing import Tuple, List

def start_project(txt: str) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    
    print("before re.search")
    x = re.search("\*\*\* START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK .* \*\*\*", txt)
    print("this is the new output: ", x)

start_project("*** START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK THE ILIAD ***")
```

**Output:**

```
before re.search
this is the new output:  <re.Match object; span=(0, 54), match='*** START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK THE ILIA>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked exactly.  I'd never had that sort of function/parameter declaration method before and it completely threw me off

Comment: `:str` in `def start_project(txt: str)` is a function annotation to document the argument type as a string.

Comment: ahh. So it's more for the programmer to know that the txt parameter is of type str?

Comment: for programmer and for code analyzers as a type hint.

Comment: so its basically just a comment.  Thank you!